# How to solve cmake "Could NOT find Threads" issue on Jenkins

Tags: compiling, cmake, jenkins

I'm trying to create a Jenkins job that need to build a project with CMake, but keep getting an error

```
Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
```

I've installed both

```
libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

and

```
libboost-thread1.67-dev
```

but the problem persists... I found this [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193785/how-to-get-cmake-to-recognize-pthread-on-ubuntu), but since all works fine locally I don't think that problem in a code itself and it should fixed somehow.

Does anyone faced the same issue with cmake on Jenkins and knows how to solve it?